# Extract Array from Json object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Curent Query:

```
db.getCollection("users").find({"_id" : ObjectId("606d72765bbe16d6be2f50d1")}, {"interests" :1 , "_id" :0})
```

Current Output:

```
{
    "interests" : [
        "Beaches",
        "Mountains",
        "Temples",
        "Nightlifes",
        "Shopping"
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
[
        "Beaches",
        "Mountains",
        "Temples",
        "Nightlifes",
        "Shopping"
]
```

How to get this expected output? Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = db.getCollection("users").find({"_id" : ObjectId("606d72765bbe16d6be2f50d1")}, {"interests" :1 , "_id" :0})



data.interests
```

Comment: var data = {
    "interests" : [
        "Beaches",
        "Mountains",
        "Temples",
        "Nightlifes",
        "Shopping"
    ]
}

console.log(data.interests)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = db.getCollection("users").find({"_id" : ObjectId("606d72765bbe16d6be2f50d1")}, {"interests" :1 , "_id" :0}).toArray()

console.log('Data: ', data[0].interests);
```